# The distinctions between different roots meaning "save"

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words

Is there any source which explains the textual uses and disticntions between the following roots

פ-ד-ה

ה-צ-ל (is that the root?)

י-ש-ע

ג-א-ל

(and any other similar words, even including the Aramaic פ-ר-ק)
Is there overlap in their use or do commentators see any specific choice as importing specific meaning local to that word?

Answer (score 3):

See [here](https://ohr.edu/this_week/whats_in_a_word/7847) for starters by Rabbi Reuven Chaim Klein which examines the difference getween geula and pidyon.

Also interesting that at least in Chumash, גאל\פדה\ישע typically appear in the Targum as a form of פרק which possibly means to separate a person from the control of a former master or ruler.

On the other hand, the shoresh נצל typically gets translated to שזב which indicates a type of sparing where most get destroyed/conquered/etc. while only some escape unscathed.